# asp.net mvc validationsummary css

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I define a css on validation summary?

Comment: See duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940335/surrounding-a-validationsummary-with-a-box-via-css

Answer (score 0):

As with all WebControl controls, you can use the CssClass attribute in your markup.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx