# How to show validation summary per condition in MVC3 Razor View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am not sure whether its a good practice or not but there is a need to display Validation summary conditionally. Actually, I need to display validation summary under Yellow Square so, I created a CSS class for the same and trying to do this :

```
@if (!Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
   <p>
      <span class="message-wrapper warning">
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
      </span>
   </p>                                           
}
else
{ 
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
}
```

The problem with above is, the Yellow square is visible always which not to ?
The Yellow square should be display only when there are Validation errors and these errors should be displayed within the 'Yellow Square.

I am looking for the solution. Any help in this regard much appreciated!

Comment: "Yellow square"?  What's that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940335/surrounding-a-validationsummary-with-a-box-via-css

Comment: quasi duplicate - judging from technical level seems it may need a separate q : )  Dennis if you want to post this I see you listed this link prior to me and I'll recant

Comment: @itsmatt-'yellow square' a filled span tag with yellow background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you just can change the css class for this

```
.validation-summary-errors {
    background-color: #D9FFB2;
    border:1px solid #5CBA30;
    width: 400px;
    }
```

There are several covered methods here, so I won't repeat them all : )

[Surrounding a ValidationSummary with a box via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940335/surrounding-a-validationsummary-with-a-box-via-css)

Comment: Thanks, it resolved my issue. Earlier I made a search for this issue in stackflow but I did not find the suggested link.