# Set CssClass for CustomValidator in ValidationSummary

Tags: .net, validation

I am using a custom .net validator as shown below, the custom validator only displays it's error message in the validation summary. I have set the CssClass on the validation summary and this works fine and renders out all my error messages in li tags. What I want is one of my validators to have a separate style in the validation summary, I have tried setting the values as below but the CssClass of the custom validator is never reflected in the HTML

```
<asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="Test error" ID="problemsLoggingIn" runat="server" Display="None" ValidationGroup="LoginValidationGroup" CssClass="specialCaseLi" ForeColor="" />

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" DisplayMode="BulletList" CssClass="errorMsg" runat="server" ValidationGroup="LoginValidationGroup" />
```

Gives this HTML:

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_LoginView_LoginForm_ValidationSummary1" class="errorMsgDiv" style="color:Red;">
<ul><li>Test error</li></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some CSS that will work:

```
enter code here.validation-summary-errors {
background-color: #D9FFB2;
border:1px solid #5CBA30;
width: 400px;
}
 span.validation-summary-errors {
border-bottom-color: #D9FFB2;
display:block;
}
     ul.validation-summary-errors {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border-top:none;
}
```

Check this link: [Surrounding a ValidationSummary with a box via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940335/surrounding-a-validationsummary-with-a-box-via-css)